# In vanilla JS, how do I use querySelectorAll with 2 pseudo-selectors?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm re-writing some jQuery as vanilla JS - it looks like this:

```
$('.main-container').children('.module:has(a)').not('#promo');
```

**What I've tried:**

```
document.querySelectorAll('.main-container .module:has(a):not(#promo)');
```

But using two pseudo-selectors in one statement is what's throwing me off. Using only the `:not(#promo)` selector works as it should:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.main-container .module:not(#promo)');
```

But things fall apart when I try adding `:has(a)`. What am I missing?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has  Check out the browser support.

Comment: [According to caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-has), the `has()` selector isn't supported by any browser. It's likely that jQuery specially handles the `has()` selector to make it work.

Comment: `has` is not supported in CSS/querySelector yet. So you can skip it and then `forEach` the results to see which one's have a `a` as a child. Yes, it is more work, but you have to emulate what jQuery does.

Comment: From jQuery docs: `:has() is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification,`

Comment: If I wait until the forEach to address the `:has(a)`, won't this throw off the indexes within the loop?

Comment: Post the relevant HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rearrange your selector like so:

```
var modules = document.querySelectorAll('.main .module:not(#exclude)');
```

Then `filter()` for `.module`s that `.contains(a)`

See demo and let me know if the HTML is correct or not since it's not posted

### Demo

**Index 2, 5, and 9 should be excluded**

```js
var modules = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.main .module:not(#exclude)'));

var hasA = modules.filter(function(module, index, hasA) {
  let a = module.querySelector('a');
  return module.contains(a);
});

hasA.map(function(module, index, hasA) {
  module.insertAdjacentText('beforeend', ' INCLUDED');
  return console.log(`module ${index}: ${module.textContent}`);
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: 40%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ol class='main' start='0'>
  <li class='module'><a href='#/'>LINK</a></li>
  <li class='module'><a href='#/'>LINK</a></li>
  <li id='exclude' class='module'>
    <a href='#/'>LINK</a>
  </li>
  <li class='module'><a href='#/'>LINK</a></li>
  <li class='module'><a href='#/'>LINK</a></li>
  <li class='component'>
    <a href='#/'>LINK</a>
  </li>
  <li class='module'><a href='#/'>LINK</a></li>
  <li class='module'><a href='#/'>LINK</a></li>
  <li id='include' class='module'>
    <a href='#/'>LINK</a>
  </li>
  <li class='module'>NO LINK</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Modules containing links should be selected, not the links themselves.

Comment: @asw1984 nothing a .parent can't fix

Comment: @asw1984 it would be nice to see the HTML. See updated answer.